# How can I define a specific RGB value for a "change in pixel color detection script" written in Python?

Tags: python, variables, pyinstaller, rgb, pixel

I want to know, how can I specify RGB values for a program that triggers a hotkey(2) when detecting a change in pixel color of a small area on screen being captured? I want to specify the RGB value so that when the software detects a new specific pixel color, it triggers the hotkey(2).

I have a script (main part of it below) already written that I found online, but I am working on altering it so that it only triggers hotkey 2 when detecting a new specific pixel color being present. I pasted "136, 36, 150" in between the parenthesis found at the end of "rgb_pixel" in line 6.

I used PyInstaller to compile my .py script into an .exe and it loaded up fine. However, when I press another hotkey(1) that toggles the pixel color change detection and hotkey(2) trigger, it closed, giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 126, in <module>
TypeError: rgb_pixel() takes 0 positional arguments but 3 were given
[11192] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

```
import colorama
from termcolor import cprint, colored
from pyfiglet import Figlet
from pynput.mouse import Controller, Button
from pynput import mouse
import numpy as np
import d3dshot
import time
import keyboard
import win32gui
import win32api
import os
import ctypes

kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32
kernel32.SetConsoleMode(kernel32.GetStdHandle(-10), 128)

colorama.init()

KEYBIND = "alt"
BOX_LENGTH = 4
SCREEN_X = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(0)
SCREEN_Y = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(1)

X1 = int(SCREEN_X/2 - BOX_LENGTH/2)
Y1 = int(SCREEN_Y/2 - BOX_LENGTH/2)
X2 = int(X1 + BOX_LENGTH)
Y2 = int(Y1 + BOX_LENGTH)

REGION = (X1, Y1, X2, Y2)

cprint("Setting up...")
cprint(" - [¤] Windows", "green")
cprint(f" - [¤] {SCREEN_X}x{SCREEN_Y}", "green")


time.sleep(0.5)

win32gui.GetDoubleClickTime = lambda: 0

mouse = Controller()

d = d3dshot.create(capture_output="numpy")


def rgb_pixel():
    return np.average(d.screenshot(region=REGION))


def time_elapsed(start_time):
    return str(int((time.time() - start_time)*1000)) + "ms"


f = Figlet(font="ogre")


def clear():
    os.system("cls")


def titlescreen():
    clear()
    print(CACHED_TITLESCREEN)


try:
    titlescreen()
    if input("Set custom keybind? (yes/no): ")[:1] in "yY":
        titlescreen()
        print(f"Current keybind: [{colored(KEYBIND, 'green')}]")
        print("\nPress [ESC] to continue")

        new_key = KEYBIND

        while True:
            new_key = keyboard.read_key()

            if new_key == "esc":
                break
            elif new_key != KEYBIND:
                KEYBIND = new_key
                titlescreen()
                print(f"Current keybind: [{colored(KEYBIND, 'green')}]")
                print("\nPress [ESC] to continue")

    titlescreen()
    print(f"Current keybind: [{colored(KEYBIND, 'green')}]")
    cprint("\nRunning.", "green")

    current_pixel = rgb_pixel()

    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed(KEYBIND):
            timeS = time.time()
            new_pixel = rgb_pixel()

            if abs(current_pixel - new_pixel) > 5:
                mouse.click(Button.left)
                print("[¤] Clicked within " + time_elapsed(timeS))

            current_pixel = new_pixel
        else:
            current_pixel = rgb_pixel()
            time.sleep(0.05)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

cprint("\n~ Program exited ;-;", "grey", "on_red")
time.sleep(1)
```

What this does is that when it detects a change in the pixel color being captured in a specific window, it triggers hotkey(2). This script triggers hotkey(2) when it detects a change in *any* pixel color. How can I alter it to where it only triggers hotkey(2) when detecting a specific RGB value? For context, I want it to trigger hotkey(2) when it detects (136, 36, 150), and multiple other RGB values similar to it.

Comment: post the full code or create a [example]

Comment: Edited it to a minimal reproducible example. Is this understandable?